# Add CSS Padding/Margin to Divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to place a `padding: 16px 0;`  to 3 divs floated left of each other but I'm having difficulty on how to do it.

**Example:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ifpAs

The `border-bottom: medium double red;` should be 16px below the section-one-widgets.

Why isn't this working and is there a way to do this without targeting specific div ID's such as #search, #logo, #social etc. as more widgets may be placed in later on?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. what exactly is wrong? In your example, you *do* have padding. 2. use a class (e.g. `.sections`)

Comment: 1. The border-bottom: medium double red; should be 16px below the section-one-widgets. 2. section-one-widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#section-one:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Works great, plus I don't have to create an extra div in the HTML, +1.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqJBg

Since all three inner divs are floated, they are removed from the layout and your container div just gets the 16 pixel height. Adding a clear in there makes it so it works as you would expect. Similar to a clearfix implemented by a lot of reset style sheets.

[EDIT since we don't like link-only answers]

HTML

```
<div id="section-one">
    ...
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div> <!--end #section-one-->
```

CSS

```
.clr {
  clear:both; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @idrumgood.  I didn't realize this occurred when floating the divs. +1 for the extra insight.